# Classic ASP + Motobit Pure ASP Upload + UTF-8 Charset

Tags: mysql, utf-8, vbscript, asp-classic, upload

After going to use the mysql database in utf-8 and all my pages, check the coding and include

```vb
@ Language = VBScript CodePage = 65001
```

In the HTML page, including:

```html
meta charset = "utf-8"
```

Everything was going wonderfully well until I have to change my upload system.
 
Now, I'm using the Pure Asp Upload, which for sending images, it's great, but I need your help, because the other text fields, are crazy.

I made a very simple code, with just a File field and a text field, just to exemplify, and give a Response.End () shortly after he takes the field just to try to see what happens, but after several days without success, come help.

Pure Asp Upload version is 2.06

```vb
<%@ Language=VBScript CodePage=65001%>
<%
Response.Expires = 0
Response.ExpiresAbsolute = Now() - 1
Response.AddHeader "pragma", "no-cache"
Response.AddHeader "cache-control", "private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
%>
<!--#include file="../includes/pure-upload.asp"-->
<% Session.Timeout = 60 %>
<%
Response.Expires = 0
Response.ExpiresAbsolute = Now() - 1
Response.AddHeader "pragma", "no-cache"
Response.AddHeader "cache-control", "private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
%>
<%
sAction = Request.querystring("a_edit")

If sAction = "" Or IsNull(sAction) Then
    sAction = "I" ' Display Record
else
    Dim fupload: Set fupload = New ASPForm

    Server.ScriptTimeout = 2000
    fupload.SizeLimit = 4*1000000 'limit of size per whole form
    Const fsCompletted  = 0

    If fupload.State = fsCompletted Then 'Completted

    fupload.CharSet = Response.CharSet
    x_jogadorID = fupload("x_jogadorID")
    x_jogadorNome = fupload.Item("x_jogadorNome")

    meukarma = fupload.CharSet
    response.write x_jogadorNome & "-" & meukarma
    response.End()

    ElseIf fupload.State > 10 then
      Const fsSizeLimit = &HD
      Select case fupload.State
        case fsSizeLimit
            Session(ewSessionMessage) = "<br><Font Color=red>Source form size (" & Form.TotalBytes & "B) exceeds form limit (" & Form.SizeLimit & "B)</Font><br>"
            Session(ewSessionMessageTipo) = "error"
        case else 
            Session(ewSessionMessage) = "<Font Color=red>Erro no Formulário." & Form.State & "</Font><br>"
            Session(ewSessionMessageTipo) = "error"
      end Select
    End If 'Form.State = 0 then
End If 

%>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>teste</title>
</head>

<body>
<form name="fjogadoredit" id="fjogadoredit" action="teste.asp?a_edit=U" class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  onSubmit="return EW_checkMyForm(this);" >
<input type="text" name="x_jogadorNome" id="x_jogadorNome" class="input-xlarge" maxlength="50" value="<%= Server.HTMLEncode(x_jogadorNome&"") %>">
<input type="file" id="x_jogadorFotoRosto" name="x_jogadorFotoRosto"  class="default">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The name I'm a registered test is `Amésio`, changed by:

```
amnÃƒÂ©sio
```

If I put the block below as early as the second line, the result for `Amésio` is

```
amnÃ©sio
```

```vb
<%
Response.AddHeader "Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8"
response.Charset="utf-8"
%>
```

Someone managed to use this component in this way, or managed to solve, as it did?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pure ASP upload with utf-8 filenames](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22685301/pure-asp-upload-with-utf-8-filenames)

Comment: Pointer... Don't `Server.HTMLEncode()` values otherwise it's working against the encoding you have already set. If encoding is done right there is no need to further encode the values.

Comment: Have you tried just writing out `Response.Charset` to see if it is set to `UTF-8` because you don't appear to be setting it in the page before assigning it to `fupload.CharSet` can you edit the question and add the output of `response.write x_jogadorNome & "-" & meukarma`?

Comment: Sorry I meant `Response.CodePage` if it's not `65001` then that's your problem. Set it before sending processing the HTML and you should be fine.

Comment: I define codepage on first line of code, all included files was checked, they are saved on utf-8, only  `Form.CharSet = Response.CharSet` not solved my problem... I was tried create a property get/set to work with 65001. I really know with my probelma is not simple, but,  all my pages work correct... I tried using persits.aspuload, and, when set codepage from him, work very well, but I want use Pure Asp Upload.

Comment: Have you checked that the `<!--#include file="../includes/pure-upload.asp"-->` file is also saved as `UTF-8`? Includes are just an extension of the ASP page, if it's set to anything other then `UTF-8` it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

### Understanding How IIS Processes ASP Encoding

As with all encoding issues in Classic ASP it helps to understand what purpose the various commands fulfill *(as too often people use them incorrectly, because it appears to solve the problem)*.

#### `<%@ Language = "VBScript" CodePage = 65001 %>`

This line is commonly misunderstood, the syntax `<%@` is a ["ASP @ Processing Directive"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524720(v=vs.90).aspx) and serves to tell IIS how to process the ASP page and is probably one of the most important commands when it comes to working with encoding correctly.

- `@Language` tells IIS what registered Active Scripting Language should be used to process the ASP Page.
- [`@CodePage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524967(v=vs.90).aspx) tells IIS what CodePage should be used to process the ASP Page. If the page has been saved using `UTF-8` then IIS needs to know when processing the page it should use CodePage `65001` *(otherwise known as `UTF-8`)*.

This means that `@CodePage` should always match the physical encoding that was used when the page was created. You may need to use an advanced text editor to work this out, some examples are [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) *(displays encoding on status bar in bottom right of the GUI window)* and [Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/) *(Has a hidden menu command called `Advanced Save Options` which can be accessed by customising the menu bar)*.

#### `<% Response.CodePage = 65001 %>`

Again often misunderstood, the purpose of this command is to tell IIS how dynamic strings should be encoded *(by dynamic strings we mean anything that is outputted using `Response.Write()`)*. Possibly the most important part of the entire process, if it is set incorrectly or assumed encoding mismatches can and do occur.

#### `<% Response.CharSet = "UTF-8" %>`

This command sets the `;charset=utf-8` in the `Content-Type` HTTP header when the response is sent from the Server to the Client Browser it tells the Browser that this response should be processed as `UTF-8` rather then the default.
Meaning code like

```vb
Response.AddHeader "Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8"
```

is superfluous and shouldn't be used. Also worth noting there is a command for the `Content-Type` HTTP header as well

```vb
Response.ContentType = "text/html"
```

making it even more redundant than it already was.

---

### Useful Links

- [MSDN - Setting the Code Page for String Conversions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525789(v=vs.90).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Before reading this I suggest taking a quick look at this answer

[Understanding How IIS Processes ASP Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34356187/692942)

---

AS for your specific problem I think it's down to not specifying

```vb
Response.CodePage = 65001
```

explicitly and assuming it's `65001` without checking it before assigning the `ASPForm.CharSet` property to it.

Try this

```vb
<%@ Language=VBScript CodePage=65001%>
<%
Response.Expires = 0
Response.ExpiresAbsolute = Now() - 1
Response.AddHeader "pragma", "no-cache"
Response.AddHeader "cache-control", "private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
%>
<!--#include file="../includes/pure-upload.asp"-->
<%
Session.Timeout = 60

sAction = Request.querystring("a_edit")

'Make sure both IIS and the Browser know how to process the page / response
Response.CodePage = 65001
Response.CharSet = "UTF-8"

If sAction = "" Or IsNull(sAction) Then
    sAction = "I" ' Display Record
else
    Dim fupload: Set fupload = New ASPForm

    Server.ScriptTimeout = 2000
    fupload.SizeLimit = 4*1000000 'limit of size per whole form
    Const fsCompletted  = 0

    If fupload.State = fsCompletted Then 'Completted

    fupload.CharSet = Response.CharSet
    x_jogadorID = fupload("x_jogadorID")
    x_jogadorNome = fupload.Item("x_jogadorNome")

    meukarma = fupload.CharSet
    response.write x_jogadorNome & "-" & meukarma

    ElseIf fupload.State > 10 then
      Const fsSizeLimit = &HD
      Select case fupload.State
        case fsSizeLimit
            Session(ewSessionMessage) = "<br><Font Color=red>Source form size (" & Form.TotalBytes & "B) exceeds form limit (" & Form.SizeLimit & "B)</Font><br>"
            Session(ewSessionMessageTipo) = "error"
        case else 
            Session(ewSessionMessage) = "<Font Color=red>Erro no Formulário." & Form.State & "</Font><br>"
            Session(ewSessionMessageTipo) = "error"
      end Select
    End If 'Form.State = 0 then
End If 

%>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>teste</title>
</head>

<body>
<form name="fjogadoredit" id="fjogadoredit" action="teste.asp?a_edit=U" class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  onSubmit="return EW_checkMyForm(this);" >
<input type="text" name="x_jogadorNome" id="x_jogadorNome" class="input-xlarge" maxlength="50" value="<%= x_jogadorNome & "" %>">
<input type="file" id="x_jogadorFotoRosto" name="x_jogadorFotoRosto"  class="default">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @user3067573 Well that's informative what did you try did you remove the `Server.HTMLEncode()` from the HTML input value? Fact is this will work if it isn't working for you your doing something wrong, your pages aren't saved in `UTF-8` *(including `#include` files)* is a common one. Just saying *"thanks, but not work"* just shows your lack of commitment and makes me less inclined to help you. Good luck.

Comment: @user3067573 Encoding is a complex problem and has to be systematically worked through until you understand how in works with ASP pages in IIS. That is why I provided a [detailed explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34356187/692942). There are no quick fixes!

Comment: Sory @Lankymart for incovenience. I'll close this question because I do not have the insight necessary to understand their indignation if I already tried the most basic commands, as he had explained in the context post. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @user3067573 Did you follow my comments above? You still haven't updated the code in your question so I cannot see you have tried all these steps, if you update the question it would help.