# Special characters are converted when sending a request

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, mandrill

So I'm implement mandrill in asp classic. Everything was fine so far, the mail was sent but I got a problem. When I send a parameter with special character, the content in email got converted. For example, The value I sent to mandrill is `Göran` but in email, it got convert to `GÃ¶ran`.

I have tried to change CodePage session but it didn't work. Using ajax jQuery and send the same value, the email look fine. Do I need to set up something in request

```
Response.CodePage = 65001
Session.CodePage = 65001
Set HttpReq = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
HttpReq.open "POST", "https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send-template.json", False
HttpReq.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
HttpReq.send(mandrillData)
```

Comment: Try and `Server.HTMLEncode` the values.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf why would you HTML encode when the body is being sent as JSON? They likely need to [specify `;charset=utf-8`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9254891/692942) on the `Content-Type` request header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Encoding in Classic ASP

When working with encoding in Classic ASP there is a check list you need to follow;

1. Is the ASP page saved using required encoding? If you want to work with UTF-8, the page needs to first be saved using UTF-8 encoding.
2. Does the ASP preproccessor know to process the ASP page using the specific encoding? You do this by specifying `Response.CodePage` and `Response.Charset` in your ASP page.
3. When sending encoded data to a 3rd party, do you tell them what to expect? For example, when sending JSON the `Content-Type` header is important but so is the `charset` argument to specify how the content is encoded.

   ```vb
   Call HttpReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
   Call HttpReq.Send(mandrillData)
   ```

---

#### Useful Links

- [Understanding How IIS Processes ASP Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34356187/692942)
- [More encoding advice in Classic ASP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21914278/692942)
- [What does “Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8” really mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9254891/692942)