# Chinese filename getting garbled once saved to server

Tags: file, file-upload, utf-8, asp-classic

I have a Classic ASP page with an `<input type="file"/>` control. When a file with Chinese filename is being uploaded to the server, it gets garbled into some weird characters.

Original FileName: `你好，你能听到我.jpg`

Filename in server: `ä½ å¥½ï¼Œä½ èƒ½å¬åˆ°æˆ‘.jpg`

Is there a way in which we can restrict this? My requirement is to let the user download the uploaded file later, and the original filename must stay intact.

I have added this in web.config:

```
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" fileEncoding="utf-8"/>
```

All my pages have:

```
<% codepage="65001" %>
<% Response.charset ="utf-8" %>
<% If Form.State = 0 Then 
    Form.CharSet = Response.CharSet%>

<html>
<head>
<title>Document Upload Wizard</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

I have a first page **FileUpload1.asp** which has the `<input type="file">` and then a Submit button which navigates to **FileUpload2.asp** where this is how the upload is happening:

```
Set Directory = Server.CreateObject("ActiveFile.Directory") 
Set Post = Server.CreateObject("ActiveFile.Post")
Set Post.Directory = Directory
Directory.Path = "D:\ApplicationDocuments\TEMPFOLDER\Product_Live\"
Post.Upload  Directory.Path
```

In the server I get the filename garbled.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pure ASP upload with utf-8 filenames](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22685301/pure-asp-upload-with-utf-8-filenames)

Comment: I had already come across that question before asking this one here. The solution given there is already present in my code.

Comment: Hard to guess a culprit if you do not show a [mcve].